# I need help to implement eloquent in a file in folder /public/

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need help to implement eloquent in a file in floder `/public/`
I have `/public/js/` a file that calls another in php called **getData.php**, this file in php returns a series of data from a table, I want to access that data with Eloquent but I can not.
This is part of a code "external" to Laravel and returns to declare the parameters of Database and I do not want to do it, I want to use eloquent to not have defined the parameters of the database twice.

I have used:

```
namespace iPuerto; (application is called iPuerto)
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

but nothing at all.

I get this error:

> " **Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' not found in ...**"

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('your stuff here');

try using this and see what you get

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the framework as it was designed?

Instead of creating php files in `public/`, use the routing feature of laravel.

So, in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('getData', function () {
    $rows = \DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table;");
    return response()->json($rows);
});
```

You can change the sql to what you need.

This route can be reached at `http://localhost/getData`. It should return a JSON string with your data in there.

Laravel can help you in providing better responses using the tools that come with the framework.

When the function gets more complicated, you can move the method to a Controller.

#### Links

- Routing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing
- Controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers
- JSON Responses: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses